# Using an answer to comment system with multiple inputs in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have comments fetched by AngularJS from a webservice. I then fill my HTML with AngularJS data.

There can be answers to any of these comments, and there's always an input after the comments and answer (in the same div) to answer to the whole post.

Here's the HTML showing this :

```
<div class="message" ng-repeat="post in ctrl.posts" ng-if="ctrl.posts">
...
<div class="message_answer" ng-repeat="answer in post.answer" ng-if="post.answer">...</div>
<form method="POST" ng-submit="ctrl.add_answer_to_post = post.message.add_answer_to_post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<% post.message.id %>">
                    <textarea class="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Write your message" ng-model="post.message.answer_added"></textarea>
                    <div class="message-send">
                        <button type="submit" class="general-button"><i class="fa fa-send"></i> React</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

But I have two problems here.

First, the ng-submit that I did seems dodgy.
I did this because I don't know how to get the textarea value that's in the form I submit.
Same goes for post_id.

ctrl.posts is an array of objects or empty, and ctrl.posts[0].answer is an array of objects or empty.

How do I get the values that are contained in the form I submitted ?

Comment: pass arguments to an `ng-submit` function based on what is known within your `ng-repeat` view structure

Comment: If you want to add that as an answer so I can choose it as the right answer :) It's so simple I don't know why I didn't think of this, thanks !